# How do I get the first error from CodeIgniter's validation_errors() method

Tags: php, codeigniter

Following the documentation [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html), suppose I have these validation checks in a controller

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('passconf', 'Password Confirmation', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]')
```

I can use `<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>` to give me all the rules which failed.

How do I get the *first* rule that failed validation?

Comment: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#individualerrors

Comment: @Ula That won't give you the _first_, I think to get that you need to split the validation_errors() string

Comment: @Ula That gives specific errors.  I want to display the first error.  Note: this gets more complex when you consider fields with multiple validation rules like the email example I provided.

Comment: Yes it will give you individual field errors. If you need first, which can be errors from any field. You can try to split using explode.

Comment: @DamienPirsy That's kind of what I was thinking, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: try $this->form_validation->error_array(); This is array of error messages.

Comment: @Ula `Form_validation::error_array()` belongs to CI 3.0-dev version. In CI 2.x version, you should use `Form_validation::error_string($prefix, $suffix);` or `validation_errors();` helper which is the same.

Answer (score 0):

It should be in form_helper

```
function validation_error_first() {
    if (FALSE === ($OBJ = & _get_validation_object())) {
        return '';
    }

    return array_shift($OBJ->_error_array);
}
```